# Best approach for generic filtering/sorting with REST

Tags: .net, rest, url, odata

We are building a .NET-based REST API that will be used by our single-page JavaScript app and potentially other consumers in the future. The app will have many grids displaying data and allowing the users to apply custom filters and sorting. Things like equals to, contains, greater than, less than, starts with, etc.

Is there an accepted approach to implementing this in a URL scheme? Especially the different operators. I don't think I see filters as first class resources and I probably would want to use query parameters to express the filtering/sorting.

It looks like OData provides a solution to something like this, but overall it seems a heavy-weight approach and I'm concerned about it's acceptance. Are there lighter-weight, more popular alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are considering several operations on your data: filter, sorting, etc I would say expose **IQueryable** on your endpoints and go with **OData**.

I would start [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx).

**Please note** that enabling OData on your API doesn't mean you are opening your data completely, you can *always* enable certain operations only, etc.

Check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/06/protect-your-queryable-api-with-validation-feature-in-asp-net-web-api-odata.aspx) to have a better idea on how to protect your API exposing OData.

I haven't tried any other alternative, but I guess you can always combine your routes and actions to get the functionality you need: top, filter, sorting, etc.